# Finding the displacement and distance using integral as net change concept.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

In my IB math class we are currently studying integral as net change. I’m a bit confused, so I found some problems in the workbook to try out. Here is the question I’m trying:

The graph shown represents the velocity of a particle moving along the $x$-axis from $t = 0$ to $t = 18$.
[image: graph here]

a) Find the displacement of the particle ofer the first 9 seconds.
So, we use the integral between 0 and 9 and we take the area between the shapes in that 9 seconds, right? (shown below).
[image: part a picture here]

The area for a trapezoid is $1/2 • h (b_1 + b_2)$. Using this formula, I got $1/2 • 30 (4 + 9) = 195 m$.
We also have the triangle beside the trapezoid. Using the area formula: $1/2 • b • h$. I plug in the values getting $1/2 • 9 • 18 = 81 m$. Then, we add these together and get $276 m$. Is this correct?

b) Find the total distance traveled by the particle from $0 < or equal to t < or equal to 18$ seconds.

To find the distance don’t I add the displacement I would get by adding the two trapezoids together? If I used the $195 m$ I got from the first trapezoid, then found the displacement of the second and adding them together? It would be easier than trying to use the triangle in this situation.

c) If the particle had a position of $1.5 m$ at $t = 0$ seconds, find the position of the particle at $t = 18$ seconds.

To do this, don’t I add my answer from part $b$ to $1.5 m$ and get my answer?

Comment: You may try it again but starting from the $v_x=0$ horizontal line (*not $v_x=18$* !) to the speed curve this way : from $0$ to $6$ you are going backward and have to count the surface under $v_x=0$ negatively. After $t=6$ you'll have to add the surface over the  $v_x=0$ line (going forward). Fine reset!

Comment: I'll try again : from $\,t=0\,$ to $4\,$s the speed is $v(t)=-12\,$m/s implying a displacement of $\;\int_0^4 -12\,dt=-48\,$m after $4\,$s. From $4$ to $6\,$s we have to integrate $\int_4^6 6\,(t-6)\,dt=-12$ (slope$=6$ of the line cutting the horizontal line at $t=6$). Of course it is simpler to remove the surface of the triangle under $v=0\,$ to get $\dfrac{12\times 2}2=12$ and obtain the total displacement after $6\,s$ : $-48-12=-60\,$ m. Good luck for the further *positive* displacements and a stronger reset,

Comment: ([youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ka9xWAmWBow))